# Unable to split a filename into name and extension using File::Basename

Tags: perl

I've been trying to write a script to batch process a list of media files to use avconv on it.

As the first step, I would run find on a path, export the filelist to a file, then use that as input for my script to run each command. I'm trying to use File::Basename to split each file name into the name and extension.

I came up with this apparently simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Basename;

while (<>) {
    chomp($_);
    my ($name,$path,$suffix) = fileparse($_);
    print "$name \t $suffix \n";
    #print "avconv -i $_ -c:v libx264 -c:a copy CONV-$i.mp4\n";
}
```

filelist contains:

```
#cat input.txt
./Supernatural S01E01 HDTV.avi
./Supernatural S01E02 HDTV.avi
./Supernatural S01E03 HDTV.avi
```

I ran it with: `./process.pl input.txt` and got:

```
#./process.pl input.txt
Supernatural S01E01 HDTV.avi
Supernatural S01E02 HDTV.avi
Supernatural S01E03 HDTV.avi
```

In short, it is not getting any value for $suffix.

I'm on Debian 7 x64, perl v5.14.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the suffixlist parameter.

```
my ($name,$path,$suffix) = fileparse($_, qr/\.[^.]*/);
```

Comment: That matches too much. I usually go with `qr/\.[^.\s\W]{0,5}/` or `qr/(?:\.[^.\s\W]{0,5})+/`

Comment: @ikegami, I knew that the regex I used was too broad/lax but my main goal was to point out what component was missing, not the best value for that component.  Using a regex in almost any form might be too broad.  Maybe an array of 2 or 3 ext would be the best choice for the OP.

Comment: I know -- the answer isn't all bad -- but your pattern isn't merely "not the best", it commonly fails for the type of file names with which the OP is dealing (e.g. `Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. S01E01 HDTV.avi` gives a suffix of `.H.I.E.L.D. S01E01 HDTV.avi`), and that's worth pointing out.

Comment: The regex I posted was tested and produced the proper results on my system (Win7 perl v5.16.1).  However, it has been modified by at least 2 other people and I don't know which of those versions you tested that produced the output you got.

Comment: Yours, the one I changed, `/\..+$/`. It gives `.H.I.E.L.D. S01E01 HDTV.avi` for the suffix of `Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. S01E01 HDTV.avi`. That's why I mentioned it was problematic. The one Miller provided assumes every file name has an extension, which I'm sure is correct for the OP. It won't find `.divx.avi`, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer because I don't think it will post correctly as a comment.

@ikegami,

Maybe the problem was/is that I did not properly quote the line of code.  IMO, SO as well as PM does not have a very user friendly way of posting responses.  I post in a number of other forums under the username of FishMonger and I have more difficulty posting properly formatted comments and code here and on PM than any other forum.

```
D:\test>type input.txt
./Supernatural S01E01 HDTV.avi
./Supernatural S01E02 HDTV.avi
./Supernatural S01E03 HDTV.avi

D:\test>type process.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Basename;

while (<>) {
    chomp($_);
    my ($name,$path,$suffix) = fileparse($_, qr/\..+$/);
    print "<$path> \t <$name> \t <$suffix> \n";
}

D:\test>process.pl input.txt
<./>     <Supernatural S01E01 HDTV>      <.avi>
<./>     <Supernatural S01E02 HDTV>      <.avi>
<./>     <Supernatural S01E03 HDTV>      <.avi>
```

Comment: It should be noted and obvious from my posted test script that I tested against what the OP posted.  There was no indication that there would be a need to accommodate the file naming convention that ikegami used.  If that was mentioned, then obviously I would have adjusted the regex accordingly.  I wonder, would there be as much controversy if I had hard coded '.avi' since that was the only ext that the OP posted?